# highlighting clusters or subtrees in graphViz

Tags: graph, tree, visualization, cluster-analysis, graphviz

I want to highlight various sub-trees in a given tree using different colors. e.g. consider binary tree below (I could show the edges between parent and its children)

> ```
>                       0
>
>              00               01
>
>         000     001     010        011
> ```

The task is to draw two convex/concave hulls showing 00, 000, 001 in one cluster and rest of the nodes(0, 01, 010, 011) in another cluster. GraphViz has subgraph feature which allows rectangular regions but how to highlight these non-rectangular regions.

In reality my original tree will be much bigger with more clusters. However, each cluster can physically be put into one convex hull.

Can I do this in graphViz or with any associated addons. Otherwise, are there other tools available to do this?

Comment: So, you mean you want to draw a hull to enclose the points {00,000,001} and another to enclose {0,01,010,011}? (so in this simple case it'd look like a triangle round the first and some kind of triangle or quadrilateral round the others?)

Comment: @marnir: yes, you got it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about gvmap?

sample: https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Gallery/undirected/gd_1994_2007.html 
... with links there for more info

but apparently not for Windows yet: http://www.graphviz.org/content/fwd-gvmap-windows

Comment: Sample link is dead.

Comment: https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Gallery/undirected/gd_1994_2007.html is the correct link